# Организация вывода в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

Нужно вывести произведение чисел <50, не используя условие if для проверки значения pr в выводе :

```
        {
        //
        string noelem = "Элементов не найдено";
        int[] mas = new int[Mass_TB.Lines.Length];
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
            mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Mass_TB.Lines[i]);
        //
        int sum = 0;
        int pr = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {
            if (mas[i] < 50)
                pr *= mas[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {
            if (mas[i] > 100)
                sum += mas[i];
        }
        //
            TB2.Clear();
        TB2.AppendText((pr == 1) ? ((pr >= 1) ? pr.ToString() : noelem) : ((pr <= 0) ? pr.ToString() : noelem));

    }
```

Однако, при вводе числа > 50 должно выводится "Элементов не найдено", вместо этого в выводе всегда пишет единицу. В чём дело и как это исправить?

Comment: Добавьте входные данные.

Comment: Какие именно данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант поиска произведения и суммы без условного оператора.

Формально тернарный оператор это тоже условие, но организовать вывод без него будет очень проблематично.

```
int sum = 0;
        int pr = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {                
            pr=pr*(Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] < 50)*mas[i]+Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] >= 50));
            sum  = sum+Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] > 100)*mas[i];
        }
            string output=(pr > 1) ? Convert.ToString(pr): noelem;
            TB2.Clear();
       TB2.AppendText(output);
```

Пояснение

`Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] < 50)` 1 если меньше и 0 если больше
`Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] >= 50)` 0 если меньше и 1 если больше

Выражение

```
Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] < 50)*mas[i]+Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] >= 50)
```

Если mas[i]<50, то `Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] < 50)=1`, а `Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] >= 50)=0`, получаем 1*mas[i]+0=mas[i].

Если mas[i]>=50, то `Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] < 50)=0`, а `Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] >= 50)=1`, получаем 0*mas[i]+1=1.

Comment: А зачем в строке с pr (+Convert.ToInt32...), по условию нужно произведение членов ряда строго меньше 50!

Comment: Добавил пояснение.

Comment: Да уж, без сумм после (mas[i] < 50) и (mas[i] > 100) перемножает всё подряд...

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(mas[i] >= 50) возвращает не элемент массива а перевод true,false в 1 и 0.

Comment: Как я понял там где Convert идёт сложение/умножение, а остальное для перехода на следующее число и проверку по первому условию

Comment: Я подробно расписал в ответе.

Comment: becouse, а почему нельзя сделать через счётчик???

Comment: У вас задание: найти произведение и сумму без условного оператора. Какой счетчик вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Там для вывода нельзя было использовать if для проверки значения pr

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя проверить значение переменной pr через значение этой самой pr, так как при вводе любого числа >50 будет выведена единица, то есть программа "думает", что значение pr изменялось. Это, конечно, неправильно. Вместо этого надо использовать счётчик :

```
        {
        int[] mas = new int[Mass_TB.Lines.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
            mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Mass_TB.Lines[i]);
        int sum = 0; string noelem = "Элементов не найдено";
        int pr = 1;
        int d = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {
            if (mas[i] > 50) 
            {
                pr *= mas[i];
                d++;
            }
            if (d > 0)
                TB2.Text = pr.ToString();
            else
                TB2.Text = noelem;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А почему вывод в TB находится внутри цикла прохода по элементам массива?

Comment: В задании без использования оператора if.

Comment: Вывод идёт уже после прохода, точнее проверки под условие, т.к. после ввода данных нужно проверять числа и потом выводить. Тобиш в конце выведет только одно значение в другой TextBox

Comment: А по условию, видимо, я не точно спросил...

Comment: Приведенный код содержит ошибки.

Comment: Какие именно, а вернее какой код?

Comment: Вышеприведенный. Думаю сами разберетесь.