# Использование счётчиков для проверки результата

Tags: c#, массивы, вывод, счетчики

Ниже приведён код из вопроса [Организация вывода в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069445/%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5) , содержащий ошибку, извините за тон, может я слепой, но в чём ошибка

```
{
    int[] mas = new int[Mass_TB.Lines.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++) // Ввод чисел и заполнение массива
        mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Mass_TB.Lines[i]);
    int sum = 0; string noelem = "Элементов не найдено"; // Переменные для 
    int pr = 1;
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++) // Цикл с использованием счётчика и проверкой чисел
     {
        if (mas[i] > 50) 
         {
            pr *= mas[i];
            d++;
         }
        // Проверка результата pr через значение счётчика
        if (d > 0) TB2.Text = pr.ToString();
        else TB2.Text = noelem;
     }
}
```

P.S. Учитывать, что при вводе числа могут быть отрицательными, равными единице и менее 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(В процессе написания вопроса обнаружена ошибка)

Блок кода -

```
if (mas[i] > 50) 
{
    pr *= mas[i];
    d++;
}
```

Стоит заменить на

```
if (mas[i] < 50) 
{
    pr *= mas[i];
    d++;
}
```

Так как по условию задачи нужно найти произведение чисел <50

P.S. спасибо пользователю https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/346909/becouse за раскрытие глаз на такую банальную ошибку, а то я бы всегда думал, что мой НЕисправленый способ 100% верный

P.P.S. Даже если есть какие-то более удобные способы или я опять где-то ошибся, пишите...